# Windows Phone 8 HTTPWebRequests duplicating data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpclient

I am making an app for a chatroom that uses XHR Polling. I am able to correctly query the server and receive/send data from it, but I have no idea why the XHR Polling acts uncontrollably.

This is what I have to run the XHR Polling:

```
private void MakeInitialConnection() // Now that we have the session and all the required pieces of data, we can connect to the chatroom
{
    this.XHRPolling.DoWork += (sender, args) => // Tell the XHR polling thread what to do
        {
            MakeConstantConnection();
        };
    this.XHRPolling.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => // Tell the thread what to do when the thread ends (i.e. the connection is cut)
        {
            this.OnDisconnect();
        };
    this.XHRPolling.RunWorkerAsync(); // Run the thread
}

private async void MakeConstantConnection()
{
    while (!this.isChatQuit) // Continuously send XHR requests until the connection is determined to have ended
    {
        await this.SendXHR();
    }
}

private async Task SendXHR()
{
    HttpClient chatXHR = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await chatXHR.GetAsync(currentChatURL);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (responseString == "1::")
        {
            this.OnConnect();
        }
        chatXHR.Dispose();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        this.OnErrorInConnection("SendXHR()", e.Message);
        chatXHR.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I get the data that I am expecting, however I keep getting the same data repeatedly until the app crashes. Even when I turn off networking entirely, I still keep getting duplicated data. So I have absolutely no idea what is going on. Doesn't `HttpResponseMessage response = await chatXHR.GetAsync(currentChatURL);` keep the request alive until it is fulfilled? Why is it being fulfilled when there is no network connection?

I have built a desktop app using almost the same code and that works exactly as intended. SendXHR *must* be done synchronously, otherwise the XHR polling wouldn't be XHR polling. Anyone have any ideas what is going on? I cannot seem to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Have you used Fiddler? It looks like it could be a caching problem, since the URL never changes and the action is GET.

Comment: I've tried to get Fiddler2 setup using the instructions provided [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/06/05/configure-the-windows-phone-8-emulator-to-work-with-fiddler.aspx) but I cannot get that to work either... How could a caching problem be rectified?

Comment: append a random number onto the end of the URL. The phone caches repeated requests

Comment: That fixed it. Lovely! Thank you AMR and Stephen